# directive to conditionally strip other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that will affect target elements in one of three ways: 1. leave it alone, 2. strip all other directives before they compile so the user cannot interact with it (ng-click, for example), 3. remove the element entirely.

So far, I can get all three to work but only on select elements. I have a span that is clickable, and if I apply option 2, it works just fine. The ng-click is stripped and the user cannot interact; however, applying the same logic to a button element causes a strange side-effect. First, instead of removing the ng-click, it DUPLICATES the event listener. Upon inspection, the element doesn't have two ng-click directives attached, but it does have two click listeners, and clicking it causes the same action to occur twice.

Below is the current directive and the current mock model I am using.

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  priority: 1500,
  compile(elem, attr) {
    let action = () => { /**/ };

    const currentLocation = $location.path().split('/')[1];
    const permissionsLocation = appConfig[currentLocation];
    const fullPath = attr.permissions;
    if (_.has(permissionsLocation, fullPath)) {
      const permLevel = _.get(permissionsLocation, fullPath);
      if (permLevel === 'disable') {
        action = (scope, element) => {
          attr.$set('disabled');
          elem.css({
            cursor: 'not-allowed'
            // 'pointer-events': 'none'
          });
          elem
            .addClass('no-permissions')
            .removeAttr('ng-click')
            .removeAttr('ng-keyup')
            .removeAttr('ng-change')
            .removeAttr('ng-touchstart')
            .removeAttr('ng-touchend')
            .removeAttr('permissions');
          $compile(element)(scope);
        };
      } else if (permLevel === 'destroy') {
        action = (scope, element) => {
          element.remove();
        };
      }
    }
    return {
      pre(scope, element) {
        action(scope, element);
      }
    };
  }
};
```

The model:

```
appConfig.location1 = {
      thing1: {
        perm1: 'disable',
        perm2: 'destroy',
        perm3: 'destroy'
      },
      thing2: {
        perm4: 'disable'
      }
    };
```

This is how I would apply the directive:

```
<button ng-click="blah()" permissions="thing1.perm1"></button>
```

Comment: Use the [`terminal` property of the DDO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-) to stop the compilation of the template. Modify the template and then use the [`$compile` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) in the postLink function to compile the modified template.

Comment: I can't use terminal: true because I do need other components to continue as normal, and applying that property causes other unwanted side-effects.

Comment: The re-compile in the postLink phase will compile child elements stopped by the `terminal`.

Comment: Could you post a specific example of what you mean? If it works, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through sheer experimentation, I have found that using the post method instead of the pre along with calling elem.off() right after the removal of attributes fixes my issue and removes all event listeners from the element I wish to disable. Doing just one or the other results in the same bug.

If someone can explain this behavior and maybe suggest a better solution to what I am doing, I would accept that answer.